# Does echo3D iOS SDK work with RealityKit or just SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit, realitykit, 3d-model

Hi I am considering using echo3D as part of my IOS application. I know that the IOS SDK works with SceneKit but I am inquiring on whether the SDK works with RealityKit. I see that the current way to do this is to use the loadSceneFromEntryID returns a SCNScene but is there similar functionality for RealityKit? I can't find anything about that in the docs. I am unable to find docs on this entirely.